# Java - Ranking / Matching Sentences

Tags: java

I'm looking for a way to rank / match two sentences.

For example, take the following 2 sample sentences.

1. This is a short sentence.
2. This is a long sentence having many words.

My new sentence is **This is a sentence.**

I want to compare my new sentence with existing sentences. My new sentence almost matches the Sentence 1 but only partially matches my sentence 2.

Can I have an algorithm or working example so that I could rank my new sentences. Sentence 1 should have a high rank and sentence 2 will be lower when compared with new sentence. My coding language is Java.

Comment: You want to calculate the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between your sentences.

Comment: Better consider each sentence in char array. and start compare with each sentence. Through you can get which is matching higher.

Comment: Thank you Bayle, that was fast and very helpful.

Comment: Yes Vig Nesh, that is the bottom line, but iterating large sentences (such as paragraphs) with many sentences to compare becomes resource intensive. I am looking for a more efficient way to rank.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static int getLevenshteinDistance(String s, String t) {
        if (s == null || t == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Strings must not be null");
        }
        int n = s.length(); // length of s
        int m = t.length(); // length of t

        if (n == 0) {
            return m;
        } else if (m == 0) {
            return n;
        }

        if (n > m) {
            // swap the input strings to consume less memory
            String tmp = s;
            s = t;
            t = tmp;
            n = m;
            m = t.length();
        }

        int p[] = new int[n + 1]; // 'previous' cost array, horizontally
        int d[] = new int[n + 1]; // cost array, horizontally
        int _d[]; // placeholder to assist in swapping p and d

        // indexes into strings s and t
        int i; // iterates through s
        int j; // iterates through t

        char t_j; // jth character of t

        int cost; // cost

        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            p[i] = i;
        }

        for (j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            t_j = t.charAt(j - 1);
            d[0] = j;

            for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                cost = s.charAt(i - 1) == t_j ? 0 : 1;
                // minimum of cell to the left+1, to the top+1, diagonally left
                // and up +cost
                d[i] = Math.min(Math.min(d[i - 1] + 1, p[i] + 1), p[i - 1] + cost);
            }

            // copy current distance counts to 'previous row' distance counts
            _d = p;
            p = d;
            d = _d;
        }

        // our last action in the above loop was to switch d and p, so p now
        // actually has the most recent cost counts
        return p[n];
    }

}
```

Comment: Dear Vig Nesh, Levenshtein distance is useful for single words but not for long sentences.

Comment: If this code is useful, implement it. Did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

A research group in the university of groningen (NL) ccreated an API for sentence deconstruction.

> Note: Although the userinterface is international, the recognized
>   sentences and the terminology used in the result are dutch.

Here is the interface (although dutch oriented) to proceed your search for a similar english based initiative.

http://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/bin/alpino (web interface without parameters)

Try 
[http://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/bin/alpino?words=dit is een korte zin](http://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/bin/alpino?words=this%20is%20a%20short%20sentence)
and 
[http://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/bin/alpino?words=dit is een zin](http://www.let.rug.nl/vannoord/bin/alpino?words=this%20is%20a%20sentence)

The result can be grabbed as XML.

```
<alpino_ds version="1.3">
   <node begin="0" cat="top" end="5" id="0" rel="top">
      <node begin="0" cat="smain" end="5" id="1" rel="--">
         <node begin="0" end="1" frame="determiner(het,nwh,nmod,pro,nparg)" getal="ev" id="2" infl="het" lcat="np" lemma="dit" naamval="stan" pdtype="pron" persoon="3o" pos="det" postag="VNW(aanw,pron,stan,vol,3o,ev)" pt="vnw" rel="su" rnum="sg" root="dit" sense="dit" status="vol" vwtype="aanw" wh="nwh" word="Dit"/>
         <node begin="1" end="2" frame="verb(unacc,sg_heeft,copula)" id="3" infl="sg_heeft" lcat="smain" lemma="zijn" pos="verb" postag="WW(pv,tgw,ev)" pt="ww" pvagr="ev" pvtijd="tgw" rel="hd" root="ben" sc="copula" sense="ben" stype="declarative" tense="present" word="is" wvorm="pv"/>
         <node begin="2" cat="np" end="5" id="4" rel="predc">
            <node begin="2" end="3" frame="determiner(een)" id="5" infl="een" lcat="detp" lemma="een" lwtype="onbep" naamval="stan" npagr="agr" pos="det" postag="LID(onbep,stan,agr)" pt="lid" rel="det" root="een" sense="een" word="een"/><node aform="base" begin="3" buiging="met-e" end="4" frame="adjective(e)" graad="basis" id="6" infl="e" lcat="ap" lemma="heel" naamval="stan" pos="adj" positie="prenom" postag="ADJ(prenom,basis,met-e,stan)" pt="adj" rel="mod" root="heel" sense="heel" vform="adj" word="hele"/>
            <node begin="4" end="5" frame="noun(de,count,sg)" gen="de" genus="zijd" getal="ev" graad="basis" id="7" lcat="np" lemma="zin" naamval="stan" ntype="soort" num="sg" pos="noun" postag="N(soort,ev,basis,zijd,stan)" pt="n" rel="hd" rnum="sg" root="zin" sense="zin" word="zin"/>
         </node>
      </node>
   </node>
   <sentence>Dit is een hele zin</sentence>
</alpino_d>
```

This example shows that the predicate has the same noun, but one word more than the shorter sentence....

I hope this helps you one step forward.